# Why is Bigquery logging User(anonymized)

Tags: google-bigquery

We are seeing instances in our activity logs (Under Home Tab) where the user is User(anonymized).  When I look at the logging logs, I see no information about the user / IP where I would expect to see it.  We're trying to figure out how a user is "anonymized" and how we can track down the actual users.

authenticationInfo:
{
}
requestMetadata:
{
}

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery's support for email addresses in audit logs is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/

There are only a few scenarios where email addresses will be retained.

Comment: just in case: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/#user_identities_in_audit_logs